# How to convert javascript code for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement something like the following into an Angular project: https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/NGXjda

The code compiles just fine in VS code, but when I try and preview in the browser, I get the following two errors:

1. Uncaught (in promise): TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.context.addEventListener')
2. TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.getScrollPos')

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rv4ju7

**home.page.ts**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  context = document.getElementsByClassName('loop')[0];
  startElement = document.getElementsByClassName('is-start')[0];
  clones = document.getElementsByClassName('is-clone');
  disableScroll = false;
  scrollWidth;
  scrollPos;
  clonesWidth;
  i;

  constructor() { 
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.reCalc);
    this.context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.scrollUpdate);
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(this.reCalc);
    }, false);
  }

getScrollPos() {
    return (this.context.pageXOffset || this.context.scrollLeft)  - (this.context.clientLeft || 0);
  }
  setScrollPos(pos) {
    this.context.scrollLeft = pos;
  }
  getClonesWidth() {
    this.clonesWidth = 0;
    this.i = 0;

    for (this.i; this.i < this.clones.length; this.i += 1) {
      this.clonesWidth = this.clonesWidth + this.clones[this.i].clientWidth;
    }
    return this.clonesWidth;
  }
  reCalc() {
    this.scrollPos = this.getScrollPos();
    this.scrollWidth = this.context.scrollWidth;
    this.clonesWidth = this.getClonesWidth();

    if (this.scrollPos <= 0) {
      this.setScrollPos(1);
    }
  }
  scrollUpdate() {
    if (this.disableScroll === false) {
      this.scrollPos = this.getScrollPos();

      if (this.clonesWidth + this.scrollPos >= this.scrollWidth) {
        // Scroll to the left when you’ve reached the far right
        this.setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow scrolling backwards.
        this.disableScroll = true;
      } else if (this.scrollPos <= 0) {
        // Scroll to the right when you reach the far left.
        this.setScrollPos(this.scrollWidth - this.clonesWidth);
        this.disableScroll = true;
      }

      if (this.disableScroll) {
        // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering.
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          this.disableScroll = false;
        }, 40);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Try to move the code from the contructor to ngOnInit. Do the same for the DOM quering code ` document.getElementsByClassName('loop')[0];` Your compoent is not yet rendered, you can't query it. It wil best if you add a `stackblitz` link, It will be easier to assist you

Comment: can you please provide the html also

Comment: I've moved those pieces to the ngOnInit but I'm getting the same error. Please see stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rv4ju7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your code from the constructor to `AfterViewInit`, where DOM elements are available. As a further recommendation, I would recommend that keep what you can out of the constructor. Constructor is mainly used for initializing variables, not doing any logic.

Furthermore, you have issues with `this`, `this` doesn't point to what you think it does. Take a read: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) Very useful reading! So I would recommend to use arrow functions instead of `function` to keep the context of `this`.

So change things like:

```
this.context.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
```

to:

```
this.context.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
```

Here's a fork of your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fci1un?file=pages/home/home.ts)**

*PS: where you can, make use of Angular tools instead of accessing the DOM like `.getElementById`. Just as a future hint. Many times angular has own set of tools, and accessing and manipulating the DOM from the component should be a last resort.*

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! Speaking of which, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :) Have a great weekend and happy coding!